# Exibir Taxonomy na página de edição

Tags: wordpress, taxonomia

Olá.
   Não sei o que aconteceu que não concigo fazer a `taxonomy` aparecer na página de edição dos posts. Não sei o que está faltando no código, veja:

```php
<?php
function registraIdiomas(){
   register_taxonomy(
       'idioma',
       'post',
       array(
           'label' => __('Idiomas'),
           'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'idioma'),
           'hierarchical' => true
       )
   );
}
add_action('init', 'registraIdiomas');
```

Não sei porque, o código a cima mostra a categoria **Idiomas** no menu do WordPress em **Posts > Idiomas**, mas não pararece nas opções da postagem.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Alguém sabe como posso corrigir isso?**

Answer (score 0):

Precisa inserir dar suporte ao show_in_rest

```
<?php
function registraIdiomas(){
   register_taxonomy(
       'idioma',
       'post',
       array(
           'label' => __('Idiomas'),
           'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'idioma'),
           'hierarchical' => true,
           'show_in_rest' => true, // falta isso!!!
       )
   );
}
add_action('init', 'registraIdiomas');
```